# Unknown characters during string addition

Tags: c++

I recently started self-learning C++ and went online to find some challenges. I found a challenge which required me to double every character of a string. (Example: "abcd" -> "aabbccdd")

I made a simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string doubleChar(string str) {
    string result = "";
    for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
        result += str[i] + str[i];
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    string stuff = "Example Text";
    cout << doubleChar(stuff);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected `"EExxaammppllee  TTeexxtt"`, or at least a result which I can deduce the error if the code is wrong. However, when I ran the code below, I got a rather peculiar result: `"è≡┬┌α╪╩@¿╩≡Φ"`

I'm really new to C++ and don't really know anything about it, so I have no idea what to Google online. I tried searching "Weird characters when adding strings in C++" or something like that but could not find anything. I suspect it may have something to do with `str[i] + str[i]`

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does your debugger show `str[i]` to be?

Comment: `string result = "";` the `= ""` part is not needed. The constructor will initialize the string already to an empty string.

Answer (score 8):

`str[i] + str[i]` adds two characters. Since characters cannot be added in the normal way, they are first converted to integers (using, for instance, the ASCII encoding). The resulting integer is then converted back into a meaningless character to be appended to your string.

Here's a version that does work, it avoids the adding two characters issue.

```
for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
    result += str[i];
    result += str[i];
}
```

You were unfortunate. What you wrote would have worked in many languages, just not in C++.

Comment: I see. When I added `cout << str[i] + str[i];` to the code, it did output a bunch of numbers. Thanks for the answer.